# Check if jump buffer is valid or not (non-local jumps)

Tags: c++, c

We have implemented "longjmp–Restore stack environment" in our code base. The `longjmp` routine is called by a particular `error_exit` function which can be invoked from anywhere.

Thus it is possible that when `longjmp` is called the `setjmp` routine may not have been called and the buffer can have invalid value leading to a crash.

Can I initialise the buffer to `NULL` or is there any check available to check for unset or invalid value. One way is that I can set a flag variable whenever `setjmp` is called, and I can check against that. But that is only a hack.

```
void error_exit()
{
    extern jmp_buf buf;
    longjmp(buf, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
void error_exit()
{
    extern jmp_buf buf;

    if(buf)
       longjmp(buf, 1);

    return 1;
}
```

The code is mixed C/C++, I know I can replace `setjmp` and `longjmp` with C++ exception handling everywhere, but that is not possible now, can I instead catch `longjmp` with invalid buffer which leads to a crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jmp_buf` is not particularly well documented. In linux headers, you can find something like:

```
typedef int __jmp_buf[6];

struct __jmp_buf_tag {
  __jmp_buf __jmpbuf;       /* Calling environment.  */
  int __mask_was_saved;     /* Saved the signal mask?  */
  __sigset_t __saved_mask;  /* Saved signal mask.  */
};

typedef struct __jmp_buf_tag jmp_buf[1];
```

Setting it to zero and then test whole size may be a lost of time.

Personally, I would keep a pointer to this buffer, initializing it to NULL and setting it right before setjmp.

```
  jmp_buf physical_buf;
  jmp_buf *buf = NULL;
  ...
  buf = &physical_buf;
  if (setjmp(*buf)) {
    ...
  }
```

It is the same idea as having a separate flag. Moreover you can allocate jmp buffers dynamically if necessary.

Comment: I really like your solution, I'm thinking of giving it a go, is there anything I need to be aware of?

Comment: Why did you remove `malloc`? isn't that better?

Comment: @Kartik Anand I have pushed it to the commenting text. It is better but it was not equivalent to your original post. And you need to care about freeing it before reassigning new value. I.e. `if (buf!=NULL) free(buf); buf = malloc(sizeof(*buf));` or even better `if (buf==NULL) buf = malloc(sizeof(*buf));`

Comment: You need to be careful and not to use longjmp once having exited the function with corresponding setjmp (unless you are hacking some co-routines and you know exactly what you are doing :).

Answer (score 2):

Knowing whether the buffer has been set or not is not a real problem, you could just have an auxiliary variable that holds that information.

The real problem is that you can't `longjmp` sideways, this is has undefined behavior and can't work for fundamental reasons. Once you returned from the function in which you have called `setjmp` the stack of that function is invalidated and overwritten by subsequent calls. So the `setjmp` context isn't valid anymore. And I am not talking of the `jmp_buf` itself, but of the stack state that is recorded in it.

So the only thing you can do is to have an auxiliary variable that records if you have set the buffer, and that you unset as soon that you leave the function with the `setjmp` in question.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

As far as I can see from the POSIX standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/longjmp.html  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setjmp.html http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/setjmp.h.html) `jmp_buf` is opaque, save that the latter reference requires it to be an array type:

> The `<setjmp.h>` header shall define the array types `jmp_buf` and ... `sigjmp_buf`.

I believe in practice you would be save `bzero()`-ing the buffer, and comparing it against zero before jumping to it, but in theory an all zero `jmp_buf` would be permissible on some as yet to be discovered POSIX system. If you were bothered about this (I wouldn't be), an option would be to `set_jmp` a dummy buffer to some jump point you never use, and then `memcmp` your `jmp_buf` against this dummy `jmp_buf` before doing the jump. That way you would only use legal (i.e. initialized by `set_jmp`) `jmp_buf`s.

An alternative would be to maintain a separate flag indicating whether it has been initialised (or wrap both in a `struct`).

I believe I should insert the mandatory warning on the manpage re `set_jmp` and `long_jmp`, in that it makes applications difficult to read, and has unpredictable effects on signal handling (the latter cured with `sigsetjmp()`). Also, in a C++ context it obviously does not unwind your exception handlers.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, but if I use a dummy buffer the code wouldn't the code jump to that, is it possible that `longjmp` gracefully doesn't do anything and `error_exit` function returns 1

Comment: The effect of `longjmp` on an unitialized `jmp_buf` is undefined (or more precisely, from the standard 'The effect of a call to `longjmp()` where initialization of the `jmp_buf` structure was not performed in the calling thread is undefined.') Therefore it *might* gracefully do nothing, but more likely it will do something unexpected (my bet would be on `SEGV` or bus error); you have no way of knowing.

Comment: " in a C++ context it obviously does not unwind your exception handlers" -- in fact isn't it UB in C++ to longjmp past a destructor?

Comment: Just as a side note, `longjmp` and friends are defined in the C standard (and probably also in C++). POSIX only follows what is said, there.